# Array of length bracket notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, brackets

If I want to make an array that is say of length 3 using bracket notation, should I just write: `var foo = [,,];`

I was more used to writing: `var foo = new Array(3);`

I noticed that if I removed one `,` that my code still worked which is surprising because I am accessing all 3 elements after assigning them. How is it that it would still work?

Comment: Just to note: if you need an `Array` with specific length `n`, you can use `Array(n).join().split(',')`. So, if you need an `Array` containing 100 empty elements: `Array(100).join().split(',')`.

Comment: Why not just write `new Array(100)`?

Comment: should've mentioned it. Using `Array(100)` you can't use methods like `map`. E.g. `Array(100).join().split(',').map(function(){return 1;})` returns an `Array` containing 100 elements with value 1, `Array(10).map(function(){return 1;})` an `Array` containing 100 elements with value `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u do

```
a = []
a[3] = 100
```

the indices 0,1,2 will be filled in with `undefined` for u. u do not have to set a specific array length before using certain indices. array will grow as u use it.

all these are the same:

```
a = [,,,]

b = []
b.length = 3

c = new Array(3)

d = []
d[2] = undefined
```

Comment: I did not realize it just grew. Is there any advantage to specifying the length with commas if I know what the final length should be?

Comment: @asimes `[,,,]` makes an array of 3 elements. i kno its weird. i dont think theres an advantage, maybe slightly faster if it can do allocation all at once instead of one index at a time. but thats a micro optimization.

Comment: That is weird... I guess `a = []` makes an array of length 0